# Это анонимная функция, замыкание или что-то еще?

Tags: golang

В документации к пакету нашел следующий код:

```
check:=func(err error) {
      if err != nill {
      log.Fatal(err)
      }
 }
```

Далее по коду  происходит вызов:

```
check(err)
```

как это правильно называется и для чего так делают? Почему нельзя было просто создать обыкновенную функцию :

```
func check(err error) {
 if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
     }
 }
```

и вызывать так же, как предыдущую

Comment: Я не знаю `golang`, но может быть вы угадали, и это `lambda-функция`? Хотя, как я посмотрел примеры функций на этом языке, везде этот подход используется при декорировании. Но, возможно, это просто примеры такие

Answer (score 10):

Это **не** *анонимная функция* и **не** *замыкание*. Это *"функция как переменная"* (function as value).

> Почему нельзя было просто создать обыкновенную функцию?

Без контекста не ясно. Возможно переменная `check` переопределятся в момент выполнения.

## Анонимная функция

Анонимная функция - функция, которая не может быть переопределена или вызвана повторно. Простыми словами, функция не имеет имени (анонимная) поэтому невозможно "назвать" или её повторно.

**например:**

**I**

```
callItAsCallback(data, func(response string) {
    print(response)
})
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Z8InpVJL9W

**II**

```
go func() {
    print("Hello!")
} ()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6Q0ITEMbta

## Функция как значение

Функция как значение - функция, которая может быть переопределена или вызвана повторно. Функция имеет имя переменной в которой она определена.

```
var check func()
if time.Now().Second()%2 == 0 {
    check = func() {
        print("четное")
    }
} else {
    check = func() {
        print("нечетное")
    }
}

check()
```

## Замыкание

Замыкание - функция, которая хранит данные из области видимости родительской функции. Это как "характер" функции, ее особенность.

Замыкания не возможны без функций "высшего порядка" (функции возвращающие другие функции). Исключение горутины.

**I** 
В этом примере замыкание исользовано для *инкапсуляции* приватных значений. Не очень полезно в go.
https://play.golang.org/p/7_ES6AKjlI

**II** 
Класический пример *примитивнейшей "фабрики"*(паттерн проектирования).

```
package main

func main() {
    MakePizza("сыром!")()
    MakePizza("грибами!")()
}

func MakePizza(with string) func() {
    msg := "Пицца с "
    return func() {
        println(msg + with)
    }
}
```

> Пицца с сыром!
>
> Пицца с грибами!

https://play.golang.org/p/RuQV2b04nn

Та же фабрика, но без замыкания. Это **функция высшего порядка возвращающая анонимную функцию**.
https://play.golang.org/p/YhAM0kYWba

**III** 
Ну и напоследок класический пример замыкания горутин в цикле.

**!!!! Этот пример заведомо неправильный!**

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
     for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            println(i)
        }()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

> 10
>   10
>   10
>   10
>   10
>   10
>   10
>   10
>   10
>   10

https://play.golang.org/p/jfHE9mGCV4

**Правильный вариант**, но это уже обычная **анонимная функция**.

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
     for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            println(i)
        }(i)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9

https://play.golang.org/p/lPFt-_HRY6

## Заключение

**Анонимные функции** используются как callback(передаются как параметер в другую функцию) или как возвращаемое значение в функциях "высшего порядка".

**Функция как значение** может быть использована как callback, как возвращаемое значение в функциях "высшего порядка" и для динамического переопределения логики внутри другой функции(неоправданно, но возможно).

**Функция высшего порядка** - функция возврщающая другие функции, как с замыканием так и без.

**Замыкание** - это эффект который может нести анонимная или "функция как значение" функция возвращаемая из функции высшего порядка или запущенная как горутина. Особенность в том, что функция может ссылаться на значения из родительской области видимости после *"завершения"* родительской функции.

Comment: Хм. А чем пример ТС не анонимная функция, присваиваемая переменной?

Comment: Идеальный ответ, очень понятно рассказал.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того как часто происходит вызов функции, возможно так автор пытался немного оптимизировать память. Если это огромный пакет, то возможно в этом есть смысл. Посмотри на пакет "encoding/json" там в процессе сериализации происходит составление кеша методов для каждого типа данных, что в дальнейшем ускоряет процесс кодирования / декодирования.